# Django queryset optimisation: Reverse lookup on _set with filter

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have these models and I need to do some calculations and present them to the user. I render approx 2-3k of rows which results in 4k queries done to the DB (shown from debug toolbar). Is there any way to optimize this? I've tried with prefetch_related but it just adds another query on top of 4k already that are being done..

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)


    def sum_for_this(self, taxtype, tax):
        return self.carttax_set.filter(tax__type__name=taxtype,
                                       tax__tax=tax).aggregate(
            sum=Coalesce(Sum('tax_amount'), Value('0'))
        ).get('sum')


class TaxType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Tax(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.ForeignKey(TaxType)
    tax = models.DecimalField()


class CartTax(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
    tax = models.ForeignKey(Tax)
    base = models.IntegerField()
    tax_amount = models.IntegerField()
```

What I do in template is:

```
{% for cart in cartlist %}
{{ cart.sum_for_this }}
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried with this but no effect:

```
Cart.objects.prefetch_related('carttax_set').all()
```

That method `def sum_for_this` is doing all the queries..

Comment: You could try using [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) to filter the queryset that you fetch, then do the sum in Python rather than using aggregate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use annotate with [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation). Your query will look like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q, F, Sum, Case, When, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce


cartlist = Cart.objects.annotate(
    sum=Coalesce(Sum(Case(
        When(Q(carttax__tax__type__name=taxtype) & Q(carttax__tax__tax=tax), then=F('carttax__tax_amount')),
        output_field=IntegerField()
        )), 0)
    )
```

And in template:

```
{% for cart in cartlist %}
{{ cart.sum }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This will narrow down my query.. I need data filtered by user (edited my question) and then try these annotate Coalesce or aggregate...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I need to return all Cart objects belonging to User and then do the calculations. This will filter them based  on carttax_set__tax__type__name afaik

Comment: I'm getting this response: `Cannot resolve keyword carttax_set... Choices are 'name' & 'user'..`

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I fixed my answer, now it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dima. One thing I don't get us how you get reverse lookup here. Like' cart.carttax_set' doesn't get called anywhere here.

Comment: I used carttax instead of carttax_set because in this case(filtering) we must use [related_query_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) that by default is model name. When we want to access related objects from model we must use [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) that by default is model name + _set

Comment: Thank you Dima. You were very helpful. I have accepted your answer. I'll need to look up on these queries and get a better understanding. Cheers mate!